# Extra lines in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to clean-up my .htaccess file of any unnecessary lines of code.  This is what I have on there right now:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks   
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.aicmillworks.com$ [NC]   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.aicmillworks.com/$1 [L,R=301]   
ReWriteRule ^home$ / [R=301,L]   
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^\?\ .]*)\.(?:\?|\ |$)  
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*    
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
```

The two lines after "RewriteEngine on" are for redirecting pages with non-www to www.  All lines after that, I am not sure what they do or why they are there.  Would it be better to remove them or are they important to my website somehow? What do they do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the third one does, but the rest of the rules are explained below.

```
# Redirect: prepend www. if the domain does not start with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.aicmillworks.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.aicmillworks.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect: /home to /
ReWriteRule ^home$ / [R=301,L] 

# Redirect: strip the file format. So /test.html redirects to /test
# I tried testing this on your site, but it didn't work, so I'm not sure if you have this rule enabled or not.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^\?\ .]*)\.(?:\?|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

# Block libwww-perl from your website. Usually for blocking bots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
```

As for "Would it be better to remove them or are they important to my website somehow?", they certainly won't hurt your website, so you may as well leave them.

Comment: @webbysteph any reason why you unaccepted this answer?